# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. Could not start video source. Face-Api.js and Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I have a application with rails 5 where I add the Face-api.js library for face recognition.

In my view I have the script and video for face detection and recogniton but when I go to browser and load the page the console return the follow error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at new:161
(anonymous) @ new:161
new:149 NotReadableError: Could not start video source
```

My view with scripts and webcam video:

```
<head>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'face_api'%>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "face-api.js/dist/face-api.min.js" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "face-api.js/dist/face-api.js" %>
      <script>
        const camfr = document.getElementById('camfr')
        
        const startVideo = () => {
        
            var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } };
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
                .then(function(mediaStream) {
                    var video = document.querySelector('video');
                    video.srcObject = mediaStream;
                    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                        video.play();
                    };
                })
            .catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); }); // always check for errors at the end.
        }
        
        Promise.all([
           faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/tiny_face_detector/tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json') %>"),
           faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/face_landmark_68/face_landmark_68_model-weights_manifest.json') %>"), //desenha os traços do rosto
           faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/face_recognition/face_recognition_model-weights_manifest.json') %>"),//faz o conhecimento do rosto
           faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/face_expression/face_expression_model-weights_manifest.json') %>"),//detecta expressoes
           faceapi.nets.ageGenderNet.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/age_gender_model/age_gender_model-weights_manifest.json') %>"),//idade e genero
           faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/ssd_mobilenetv1/ssd_mobilenetv1_model-weights_manifest.json') %>") // usada para detectar rosto
        ]).then(startVideo)
        
        camfr.addEventListener('play', async () => {
        const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(camfr)
        const canvasSize = {
            width: camfr.width,
            height: camfr.height
        }
        faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, canvasSize)
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
        setInterval(async () => {
            const detections = await faceapi
            .detectAllFaces(
                camfr,
                new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()
                )
                .withFaceLandmarks()
                .withFaceExpressions()
                .withAgeAndGender()
                const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, canvasSize)
                canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
                faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
                faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
                faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)
        
                resizedDetections.forEach(detection => {
                    const {age, gender, genderProbability} = detection
                    new faceapi.draw.DrawTextField([
                                `${parseInt(age, 10)} years`,
                                `${gender} (${ parseInt(genderProbability * 100, 10)})`
                            ], detection.detection.box.topRight).draw(canvas)
        })
        
        }, 100)
        })
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <video autopĺay id="camfr" width="400" height="400" muted></video>
    </body>
```

I doesnt understand what this doesnt work the face-api.js is on vendor/assets/javascripts, in assets.rb i make the pre compile of new javascripts and models of face-api.js.

my face-api.js

```
//= require face-api.js/dist/face-api 
//= require face-api.js/dist/face-api.js 
//= require face-api.js/dist/face-api.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<head>` tag loads before the rest of the page, and hence the DOM isn't loaded when `camfr = document.getElementById('camfr')` runs. You need to wrap your script in an event to ensure the DOM is fully loaded before it executes. If you're using turbolinks:

```js
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const camfr = document.getElementById('camfr');
  if (element) {
    ...
  }
});
```

If you aren't using turbolinks you can use the `onload` event instead of `turbolinks:load`.

Also, The 'Rails way' of using Javascript would be to extract your code into a separate `.js` file in the asset path (or webpacker pack if you are using Rails 6) rather than embedding directly into a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Ok, I extract the code of the tag script and put the code in lib/assets/face_recognition.js, in my app/assets/javascripts I create a file face_recogniton.js and add //require face_recogniton and in my view I add  <%= javascript_include_tag 'face_recognition'%>, but my video doesnt start in browser and dont show errors in console of browser.